# PHP - How to get words starting with # and remove the others from string

Tags: php, replace

```
$query = "Hello #world What's #up"
$newquery = "world, up"
```

So basically I wan't to remove the words not starting with #

Comment: split on spaces and then loop over each element and see if it starts with "#".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the string on spaces and loop over the resulting array, checking if the first character is a `#` or not. Something like:

```
$bits = explode(' ', $query);
$newquery = array();

foreach($bits as $bit){
    if(strlen($bit) > 0 && $bit[0] === '#') $newquery[] = $bit;
}

$newquery = implode(', ', $newquery);
```

You can also use a regular expression such as `(?:\#([^\s]+))` to get matching words.

**EDIT:** As [Scopey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3163506/scopey) pointed out, my initial regex can be improved (changed below) and you should use `$matches[1]`, as the returned array is multi-dimensional. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

That might look something like:

```
preg_match_all('/#([^#\s]+)/', $query, $matches);

$newquery = implode(', ', $matches[1]);
```

Comment: +1 for the `preg_match_all` answer, but the regex can me improved to `/#([^#\s]+)/` as this will take into account any matches like `#hello#test` where they are appended to one another. You will also have to implode matches like so: `implode(', ', $matches[1]);`. You cannot use `g` as a regex modifier either.

Comment: I think the 'g' modifier only works in Javascript. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Scopey Impressive regex. I need to work on mine a little. I'm curious if you could make the cleans the string with preg_place()? Or do you think it's possible?

Comment: Well it worked well now how can I delete strings starting with #

Comment: @Smixen - Use `preg_replace('/#([^#\s]+)/', '', $query);` to replace strings starting with `#`.

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha - I came up with `preg_replace('/(^|\s)(?!#)[^#]+/', '', $query);` - Is that what you were thinking? - http://regexr.com/39jso

Comment: Very nice yes. Yeah, every time I'd try to do a (not match) replace, I had trouble, I can learn what I wanted from this, so thank you.